# How to filter with wildcard in Android.mk

Tags: android, wildcard, android.mk

I am trying to tweak one Android.mk module for a specific usage so it could be built only for a specific TARGET_PRODUCT. So, I inserter something like this:

```
ifneq ( ,$(filter product_name,$(TARGET_PRODUCT)))

...

endif # TARGET_PRODUCT
```

Problem is, it works for a `product_name`, but I want it to work also for a `product_name1`, `product_name2`, `product_surname` etc. So how could I insert wildcards instead second word? Something like `product_*`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use "%" as a wildcard:

```
ifneq ($(filter product_%,$(TARGET_PRODUCT)),)
...
endif # TARGET_PRODUCT
```

See http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html

Answer (score 2):

I dont know about wildcard.
But if you are having 2 or 4 names you can try below method

```
ifneq ( ,$(filter product_name product_name1 product_name2 ,$(TARGET_PRODUCT)))

...

endif # TARGET_PRODUCT
```